# Express JS serve public folder via GET endpoint

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have a folder called `my-folder`, and inside it, many other folders. I'm trying to serve HTML and assets like JS and CSS when I go to a route using Express JS. I'm trying:

```js
router.get('/serve/test', (req, res) => {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'my-folder/test/public')))
})
```

Inside of `my-folder` is various folders, and in each of those is again different folders, and I'd like to be able to serve the folder's `public` directory from any folder within `my-folder` in order to link to JS, HTML and CSS when going to: http://example.com/serve/test

Right now, I've hard-coded a folder of `test`, but this would be changed via a param...

Any thoughts as to why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the parent folders beforehand. You could use multiple `express.static` outside `router.get`. Like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'my-folder/test/public')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'my-folder/test2/public')))
...
app.get(...)
```

If you don't know the folder names beforehand then you will need to build it as a route and return files with `res.sendFile`:

```
app.get('/my-folder/:uid/*', function(req, res){
  var uid = req.params.uid, path = req.params[0] ? req.params[0] : 'index.html';
  res.sendFile(path, {root: `./my-folder/${uid}/public/`});
});
```

The example above will serve the requested path file or "index.html" if no path is provided.

Comment: Do you reckon I can do: `express.static("my-folder/**/public")` since I need any folder in here. And I need to serve this on it's own endpoint, not on `/`

Comment: The folder names are not known, and are generated using UUID's, e.g: `c963420f-855b-4903-845a-9d998f320b24` so there could be one folder, and there could be 100 folders, I need to serve a specific folder by going to for example: http://example.com/server/c963420f-855b-4903-845a-9d998f320b24 and this would serve the public folder of that directory

Comment: You're a star! This is excellent! Looks like I was missing the `root` option?

Comment: Perhaps yes, `root` is now required since the last version of Express for security reasons. Please note I made a few changes in the code so that users don't need to include "public" in the URL *and* files are now obtained from its own "public" folder.